# Drupal, leaflet views open a map popup and call some jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal, popup, leaflet

I’m using leaflet 7.x-1.1  ,  IP Geolocation Views & Maps 7.x-1.27 and I have a real hot map set up to render the leaflet map via ip geo views and maps, what I’m looking to do is call JavaScript from inside a map popup;

Heres a link to a similar solution that I could implement but I don’t know where to insert the code: [Click link inside Leaflet Popup and do Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript)

Also tried the leaflet popup outside module, but it doesn’t work, and a couple java injectors from drupal neither of them work.   This seams like it should be pretty basic functionality.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks

Comment: You want to use javascript to control content instead a leaflet popup? or bind an event to clicking on something inside a leaflet popup?

Comment: Bind event to something inside leaflet pop up or something equivelent

Comment: Any luck nicemaestro? I'd like to do the same thing...

Comment: nada it seams that the this is not in the cards... I know there;s some websites out there that offer this kind of functionality, so i;ll keep baking till I make cake.