# Submit a form from a leaflet popup Mysql

Tags: mysql, forms, popup, submit, leaflet

I would like to submit a form from a leaflet popup to modify datas in a mysql db.

```
lyrClients.eachLayer(function(e){ 

                    if(e.feature.properties.IdClient==IdClient){
                        e.bindPopup("<form method='post' action='ajax/filldbclient.php'>First name:<br><input type='text' name='firstname' value='Your first name' ><br>Last name:<br><input type='text' name='RaisonSociale' value='Your last name'></form><input class='click' type='submit' name='submit' value='Sent'>" );              
                        e.openPopup();
                    }



        });
```

This does not work because as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript) click event seems to be disable in popup. But I did not found the way to make it works.. (I mean for a submit) Thanks by advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input button element needs to be within the form element:

Change:

```
</form><input class='click' type='submit' name='submit' value='Sent'>
```

To:

```
<input class='click' type='submit' name='submit' value='Sent'></form>
```

Comment: Thanks iH8 ;) sorry for those stupid questions, I'm starting with all those languages

Comment: No thanks, no problem, always welcome. Don't feel bothered, every developer on the planet has/had to learn to get where they are today. Cheers & good luck!