# How to import html text in a leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, leaflet

I have a pretty map with a cool event that trigger a map.onclick event like that :

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    L.popup()
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent('<link rel="import" href="./pages/myPopup.html">')
        .openOn(mymap);
    }
mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

And i'm trying to import html text in my leaflet popup.
I'm using bootstrap+JQuery and I already saw [bootstrap3-dialog](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog) but I think there is something to try [with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) or with jquery, but I don't know how !

I also found some explanations for having a [click link inside leaflet popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript) that help for the start ! ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lnt4/))

Comment: How exactly do you want your "html text" to appear? should it be a new page, an insert in the Leaflet popup, a link that user should click to be redirected to that page?..

Comment: oh inserted in the leaflet popup !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sound to be looking for a simple [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) (instead of your strange `<link>` tag which is for the page `<head>`) embedded in a Leaflet popup.

```html
<iframe src="./myPopup.html"></iframe>
```

This is extremely simple and does not present any particular issue. Do not forget to set height and width on your iframe.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/m94za7fHpGakqouMmwO2?p=preview

Comment: arf ! It wasn't the best solution in my point of view but all the others solutions ([detailled there](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) ) didn't worked for me so I wanna do this ...
Thank you for your answer ! =)

Comment: for some reason, this is embedding my whole app inside the popup, even if I am pointing towards a static html file

Comment: @Louis please open a new question with specific details of your issue if you have a different problem.